# display all users profiles

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I need to display **all users profiles properties**, not one but all as a list. Can anyone point me in the right direction with some code?
Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What info do you need? It could be done with Search API

Comment: I need to display all the properties. Can you provide me some code?

Answer (score -1):

Well this is actually a very easy task using the SharePoint Client APIs.

First you get the SP Context if you're using SSOM (it's called Client Context when you are using CSOM).

You get the web from the CSOM, and then go through one of the three available SPUserCollection properties on the SPWeb object.

Find an example with screen shots I wrote here: http://mazdev.blogspot.ae/2014/05/webpart-example-1-users-list-web-part.html

If you want a more powerful users profile, it's just a matter of exploring, well, the UserProfiles API. Just reference the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.DLL and go from there.

The default location on the SharePoint server is here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll

If you are using JSOM, it is similar.